# How to rotate and then move on that direction?

Tags: c++, opengl

Hy, I am currently trying to make a first person game.what i was able to do was to make the camera move using the function gluLookAt(), and to rotate it using glRotatef().What I am trying to to is to rotate the camera and then move forward on the direction i have rotated on, but the axes stay the same,and although i have rotated  the camera moves sideways not forward. Can someone help me ? this is my code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);   
glLoadIdentity();   
glRotatef(cameraPhi,1,0,0);   
glRotatef(cameraTheta,0,1,0);
gluLookAt(move_camera.x,move_camera.y,move_camera.z,move_camera.x,move_camera.y,move_camera.z-10,0,1,0);
drawSkybox2d(treeTexture);
```

Comment: You may find this website more helpful: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This requires a bit of vector math...

Given these functions, the operation is pretty simple though:

```
vec rotx(vec v, double a)
{
    return vec(v.x, v.y*cos(a) - v.z*sin(a), v.y*sin(a) + v.z*cos(a));
}

vec roty(vec v, double a)
{
    return vec(v.x*cos(a) + v.z*sin(a), v.y, -v.x*sin(a) + v.z*cos(a));
}

vec rotz(vec v, double a)
{
    return vec(v.x*cos(a) - v.y*sin(a), v.x*sin(a) + v.y*cos(a), v.z);
}
```

Assuming you have an orientation vector defined as {CameraPhi, CameraTheta, 0.0}, then if you want to move the camera in the direction of a vector v with respect to the camera's axis, you add this to the camera's position p:

```
p += v.x*roty(rotx(vec(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), CameraPhi), CameraTheta) +
     v.y*roty(rotx(vec(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), CameraPhi), CameraTheta) +
     v.z*roty(rotx(vec(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), CameraPhi), CameraTheta);
```

And that should do it.
Keep Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

`gluLookAt` is defined as follows:

```
void gluLookAt(GLdouble eyeX, GLdouble eyeY, GLdouble eyeZ,
               GLdouble centerX, GLdouble centerY, GLdouble centerZ,
               GLdouble upX, GLdouble upY, GLdouble upZ
              );
```

The camera is located at the `eye` position and looking in the direction from the `eye` to the `center`.

`eye` and `center` together define the axis (direction) of the camera, and the third vector `up` defines the rotation about this axis.

You don't need the separate phi and theta rotations, just pass in the correct `up` vector to get the desired rotation. `(0,1,0)` means the camera is upright, `(0,-1,0)` means the camera is upside-down and other vectors define intermediate positions.

Comment: They are not the same in his code, look carefully, he subtracts 10 from `centerZ`.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Thanks, I've removed that part.