# Opengl: moving the camera "fps style"

Tags: opengl, 3d

I want to move the camera inside a 3D scene [like this](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/692/roomzc.jpg) in a first person shooter style, how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your questions is rather general so I'm going to point you over to the great NeHe tutorials which can explain this far better than I can in the space allowed for SO Answers...

http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/articles/article.asp?article=08

This topic can get very in-depth but the above article is a good start at understanding matrix transforms and how it interacts with a "camera".

Comment: article doesn't exists

Comment: I can't delete an accepted answer which this should probably be. It is very out of date.

Answer (score 5):

[How to rotate and then move on that direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288367/how-to-rotate-and-then-move-on-that-direction/4295217#4295217)
[OpenGL: creating my own camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294596/opengl-creating-my-own-camera/4295174#4295174)