# OpenGL - Confused with transformations based on former transformations

Tags: opengl-es, transformation

I've i've written a simple program by openGL ES 1.1, on android which draws 3D objects with ability to navigate through the space.

I want to move left, right, in, out and rotate left, right, up, down like first person camera mode in 3D games. (this means I want to rotate camera/eye itself) 
here's my drawing part in `onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)`:

```
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glRotatef(lfRt, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glRotatef(upDn, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(X, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, Y, 0.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, Z);
```

lfRt and other variables determines the point we must be there. (To describe more, every moveIn() call pluses the z with some constant. others are with same logic).

Now here is my confusion. If I put the translations first, move methods work fine (in, left, etc.) but rotations are wrong. (whole world rotates around origin)
On other hand, if I put rotations first, camera rotates fine but move methods go incorrect. for example moveIn() always move in same line/axis. but I want to move through not moving on z-axis

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the rotation first and then do the translation in this scenario.Remember, matrix operations are non-commutative.[Here](http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/camera2.html) is a simple example for FPS camera .[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389687/opengl-moving-the-camera-fps-style) thread is also helpful.